# Use opengl with c# without external libraries

Tags: c#, opengl

I have recently gotten into coding with opengl. I have used lwjgl and other wrappers for opengl. I am curious if it is possible to create a simple 3d program without the use of external libraries or programs. Using solely c# and the opengl libraries, is it possible to create a simple 3d program? If so, how would one go about doing that.

Comment: Sort of.  You can call native code from C# using P/Invoke (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services), but you'll probably find it easier to use a wrapper.

Comment: Just to add - these wrappers usually just use P/Invoke to call the native code, so in effect you would just be rewriting the wrappers.

Comment: Ok. that makes more sense. Thank you for the answers.